# Button submit e criação de componentes dinamicamente em ReactJS

Tags: javascript, react

Estou fazendo uma página de cadastro de receitas. Esse é o meu form:

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <Input 
        name="title"
        label="Nome da receita:"
        type="text"
        value={title}
        onChange={(event) => { setTitle(event.target.value)}}
      />
      
      <div>
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Ingrediente</th>
              <th>Quantidade</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div >
        <Input 
          
          name="ingredient"
          label=""
          type="text"
          value={ingredient}
          onChange={(event) => { setIngredient(event.target.value)}}
        />
        <Input 
          
          name="quant"
          label=""
          type="text"
          value={quant}
          onChange={(event) => { setQuant(event.target.value)}}
        />
      </div>
        <button onClick={handleIngredient}>
          Incluir ingrediente
        </button>
        
      <TextArea 
        name='direction'
        label='Modo de fazer:'
        type="text"
        value={direction}
        onChange={(event) => { setDirection(event.target.value)}}
      />
      <div>
        <button type="submit">
          Cadastrar receita
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Quando o usuário clicar no botão Incluir ingrediente, eu gostaria que a página mostrasse mais dois inputs, um para o ingrediente e outro para a quantidade. Até o momento eu criei o seguinte. (Esse trecho é chamado na função handleIngredient):

```
function handleIngredient( ){
     <>
      <div>
        <Input 
          name="ingredient"
          label=""
          type="text"
          value={ingredient}
          onChange={(event) => { setIngredient(event.target.value)}}
        />
        <Input 
          name="quant"
          label=""
          type="text"
          value={quant}
          onChange={(event) => { setQuant(event.target.value)}}
        />
      </div>
        <button onClick={handleIngredient}>
          Incluir ingrediente
        </button> 
    </>
```

}

Mas ele não retorna os inputs, e o pior: ele retorna o conteúdo do handleSubmit.
Então, eu tenho essas duas questões:
Como eu faço para criar esses dois inputs a partir do clique do botão;
Por que esse botão (que não é submit) chama a função do Submit.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Geralmente quando se começa com `React` essa é uma das dificuldades de entender o(s) estado(s) de um componente e quando se quer criar elementos que poderão ter uma lista no seu caso são ingredientes de uma receita o seu componente precisa ter uma lista de ingredientes para que ao clicar em um botão tenha o efeito da adição de novos ingredientes para essa receita, um exemplo básico:

```js
function App() {
  const valueBase = {description: '', quantidade: 0};
  const [ingredientes, setIngredientes] = 
    React.useState([{...valueBase}]);
  const handleAdd = () => {
    setIngredientes(state => [...state, {... valueBase}]);
  }
  const handleChange = (e, ix) => {
    const {name, value} = e.target;
    let values = [...ingredientes];
    values[ix][name] = value;
    setIngredientes(state => [...values]);
  }
  const handleDelete = (ix) => {
    let values = ingredientes.filter((a, b) => {    
      if (b !== ix) {
        return a;
      }
    });
    setIngredientes(state => [...values]);    
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        {ingredientes.map((ing, ix) => (
          <div>
            <label> Descrição:
            <input name="description" type="text" value={ing.description} onChange={e => handleChange(e, ix)} style={{width: 100}} />
            </label>
            <label> Quantidade:
            <input name="quantidade" type="number" value={ing.quantidade} onChange={e => handleChange(e, ix)} style={{width:50}}/>
            </label> { ' ' }
            <button onClick={e => handleDelete(ix)}>Remover</button>
          </div>
        ))}
        <br />
        <br />
        <button onClick={handleAdd}>Adicionar Ingrediente</button>
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(ingredientes, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Quando se quer duplicar itens no componente, crie sempre um `array`, exemplo

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState([]); // [] significa lista, array
```

e em cada posição um objeto (`{}`) com as chaves que assim necessitar. Fiz também nesse exemplo a exclusão de algum ingrediente que por ventura foi adicionado erroneamente.

Comment: Ajudou muito amigo, valeu mesmo